# Parser generators for context-sensitive grammars

Tags: c#, nlp

I see that there are quite an unending list of parser generators for context-free grammars. Aside LuZc, are there any good parser generators for context-sensitive grammars? I need to use one for a Natural Language parsing task?

Comment: I'm asking myself the same question. Let's gather ressources. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_parser_generators

Comment: I founds some other examples of parser generators for context-sensitive grammars, such as [Nez](http://nez-peg.github.io/) and [RBNF](https://github.com/thautwarm/RBNF).